# Is there any solution for filling the dashedline's gap color?

Tags: svg

I need to fill the color of the dashed line's gap.

I achieved this need by using a solid line and a dashed line. The solid line works as the background.
I don't know if there exists better solution. Thanks for your help! :)

Here is my demo:
[dashed polyline background color demo](https://codepen.io/cactusxx/pen/eYbgpgz)

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
  <path d="M50 10 l100 50, 100 -50, 100 50" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 193, 33, 1.0)" stroke-width="5"/>
  <path d="M50 10 l100 50, 100 -50, 100 50" fill="none" stroke="rgb(226, 193, 33)" stroke-width="5"  stroke-dasharray="10, 10"/>
  <path d="M50 30 l100 50, 100 -50, 100 50" fill="none" stroke="rgb(226, 193, 33)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="10, 10"/>  
</svg>
```

Comment: What would make any other solution "better"?

Comment: Your solution is the only solution. A ""better"" solution would be to only define a d-path _**once**_; but that requires extra (Web Component) code to read the d-path and duplicate it with code. A solution if you need to draw multiple paths, and you don't want to copy paste SVG code.

Comment: @RobertLongson The "better" I means maybe there exists some properties can set this need, I don't know... I tried, but I didn't find a "better" solution.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thanks for your reply. Maybe my solution is the simplest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like commented you already made something that works. Depending on the use case it could be useful to reuse the path and to have a mask that only shows the "space in between" the dashes. Now, colors can be opaque without interfering with each other.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
  <defs>
    <path id="p1" d="M50 10 l100 50, 100 -50, 100 50" fill="none" stroke-width="5" />
    <mask id="m1">
      <use href="#p1" stroke="white" />
      <use href="#p1" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="10 10" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <use href="#p1" stroke="rgb(0, 193, 33, 1.0)" stroke-dasharray="10 10" />
  <use href="#p1" stroke="rgb(226, 193, 33)" mask="url(#m1)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! I learn more knowledge about SVG from your answer.  Unfortunately, I applied this solution to my project, and it did not work. I used my original method in the question description, and it worked. I found it seems like my project dose not support <mask>. Actually, I did not find why your answer was not working. Anyway, THANKS.

Comment: I finally found the reason why it did not work when I used your solution. This is because I used the wrong mask id in my program.

Comment: @personax I'm glad to hear that you got it to work.