# Is there a way to composite overlap area between two lines in SVG

Tags: svg

I have a line with an arrow (let's call it foreLine), and now I want to fill the backgroundColor of this line. I tried placing a backLine behind it. It works okay when foreLine has a color with opacity 1.0. However, when I set the opacity to less than 1 for foreLine, an overlap problem occurs. I know that moving the backLine into the  and giving it the same opacity will eliminate this issue. However, in my task, backLine and foreLine are allowed to have different opacities. I previously asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77131175/is-there-any-solution-for-filling-the-dashedlines-gap-color), and *chrwahl* provided a good solution using `<mask>` to achieve my goal. However, now I find that using `<mask>` leads to a serious performance problem. Therefore, I want to know if there is any other way to composite the overlapping area.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="350" height="200">
  <line id="backLine" x1="100" y1="50" x2="300" y2="50" stroke-width="10" stroke="red" opacity=0.5 stroke-linecap="round" />
  <g opacity=1>
    <line id="foreLine" x1="100" y1="50" x2="300" y2="50" stroke-width="10" stroke="blue" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="40 40" />
    <path id="arrow" d="M100,50 L100,35 L70,50 L100,65 Z" fill="blue" stroke="blue" stroke-width="20" stroke-linejoin="round" />
  </g>
</svg>

<svg width="350" height="200">
  <line id="backLine" x1="100" y1="50" x2="300" y2="50" stroke-width="10" stroke="red" opacity=0.5 stroke-linecap="round" />
  <g opacity=0.5>
    <line id="foreLine" x1="100" y1="50" x2="300" y2="50" stroke-width="10" stroke="blue" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="40 40" />
    <path id="arrow" d="M100,50 L100,35 L70,50 L100,65 Z" fill="blue" stroke="blue" stroke-width="20" stroke-linejoin="round" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Maybe you're making the mask too big.